# "#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'" when trying to reset AI after backup

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've restored my Wordpress database from an sql backup. However, in doing so, all of the tables have lost auto increment.

When I try to add it back in with this sql

```
ALTER TABLE `mercury_posts` CHANGE `ID` `ID` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

I get the error `#1067 - Invalid default value for 'post_date'`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like your tables were set to MyISAM instead of InnoDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this by deleting the faulty database, backing up again from the working database but exporting structure and data separately.

Answer (score 14):

The post_date default value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00. If you check the sql_mode variable like this:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
```

... it will show you the sql_mode variable, that will be sth like this: **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION**

You have to set up again sql_mode variable without
**NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE**

So in the previous example you should set the sql_mode like this:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Then check the sql_mode variable again to be sure it has changed correctly:

```
show variables like 'sql_mode';
```

Then the restriction is gone ;D

Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696251/504910

Comment: The above added an incorrect AUTO_CREATE_USER. The correct code was in the linked URL (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696251/504910)
set global sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

Comment: The code I wrote is without NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE. The original sql_mode variable in my system was with NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER so I left it that way.

Comment: @CarlosFaria provided code does not work for the described problem. But the code provided by `popealope` works fine. Therefore i prefer to correct this in the post.

Answer (score 10):

You must to add this code at the top of your SQL

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
```

Comment: `SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";` this has solved it for me

Answer (score 3):

**You can use following command to change your default post_date:-**

```
  ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
  CHANGE `post_date` `post_date`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: This should be how Wordpress creates new schemas.

Answer (score 1):

First run

```sql
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
  CHANGE `post_date` `post_date`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_modified` `post_modified`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  CHANGE `post_modified_gmt` `post_modified_gmt`  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

then after auto increment

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Changing sql_mode to

ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

works, but it only lasts until you restart the sql server.

So in case you need it again, you have to change sql_mode again.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer of Carlos Faria](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/313069/134512) is perfect !

But here is a small code you can use if you are on PhpMyAdmin and doesn't want to mess with the SQL configuration.

Here I gonna change the `sql_mode` value but only for the session, just the time needed to alter the table :

```
SET SESSION sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE',''));

ALTER TABLE wp_posts auto_increment = XXX;
```

(Don't forget to change the table prefix `wp_` and replace `XXX` by the new AI value you want)